# How to change textcolor of materialbutton which is styled outline if my apptheme's primary color is white?

Tags: android, android-button, material-components-android

> I have made my AppTheme's colorprimary white, but while using the Material Button with outline style the text color shows is white.

Is there something that I can do in my styles.xml?

style.xml file

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/foopprimary_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/foopprimary_900</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/foopsecondary_500</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@string/default_font</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/foopsecondary_500</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/foopsecondary_500</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/foopprimary_500</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/foopsecondary_500</item>
</style>
```

color.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<color name="foopprimary_50">#ffffff</color>
<color name="foopprimary_500">#ffffff</color>
<color name="foopprimary_900">#ffffff</color>
<color name="foopprimary_A400">#ffffff</color>
<color name="foopsecondary_300">#ff824d</color>
<color name="foopsecondary_500">#ff4d00</color>
<color name="foopsecondary_900">#ff2500</color>
<color name="foopsecondary_A100">#ffffff</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_50">#e4e4e4</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_100">#bcbcbc</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_200">#909090</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_300">#646464</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_400">#424242</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_500">#212121</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_900">#0b0b0b</color>
<color name="fooptextprimary_A400">#ec0000</color>
</resources>
```

xml for Button

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/promote"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Output is something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the primary color in your `MaterialButton`:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Primary"
    ../>
```

with:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.Primary" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Or you can define a custom style using:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    .. />
```

with:

```
<style name="Widget.App.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Primary</item>
</style>
```